# Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) macro not showing

Tags: vba, excel

I recently found a macro that changes text and cell color based on a partial value in a cell but the macro doesn´t show up in the list when I press F5.

**Macro**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Range
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim A As Long

    Set i = Intersect(Target, Range("TestRange"))
    If Not i Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cel In i
            A = UCase(Cel.Text)
            If InStr(A, "NEW") Then       'Green text and bold
                With Cel.Font
                    .Color = -11489280
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Bold = True
                End With
            End If


End sub
```

I suspect it has something to do with the sub taking an argument. Could someone confirm if this is the case? If this is true, it needs to be passed as an array, but I have no clue how to do this properly. Could someone also help me with this?

Much obliged,

B. van Starkenburg

Comment: It's an event handler. It's not supposed to show in that list. It is also due to the fact that it accepts a parameter, and that parameter should not be passed as an array. The parameter is declared `As Range`. If you want to call this handler manually, please do, providing a `Range` as the parameter.

Comment: (1) This macro is an event that runs automatically when a cell in a worksheet changes `Worksheet_Change` so this is not meant to run manually (Also procedures awaiting a parameter can only be run from another sub/function). **(2) This VBA code is incomplete at least there is a `Next Cel` and an `End If` missing so it won't run.**

Comment: That's right. Moreover, Worksheet_Change is an event, which is part of the event factory of Excel. If you want to try this macro, just modify a cell, in your "TestRange" range.


 If you want to try it manually, I would recommend create another macro, Like `Private Sub test()` and on `test()`, you call `Worksheet_Change` with your parameters. A thing like
    
 `Private Sub test()
    Call Worksheet_Change(Range("A1"))
End Sub`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll try to rewrite it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Or create the proc and call that from the worksheet_change event, passing `target` as the argument.  Have you considered conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample macro from your question is an Event handler: It gets fired when the Worksheet changes, e.g. when you enter a cell value. Thus, this code needs to be placed in a `Worksheet` module and will be executed when something on the corresponding worksheet is changed. Read up on Excel VBA events over at [Chip Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/events.aspx)

Secondly, macro's show up in the Macro list when:

- They do not take any parameters
- They are `Public` (declared as `Public Sub` or `Sub` in a module that is not set to private)
- They are placed in a Regular Module

Last but not least, in order to have this Macro show up in the Macro list and execute against the "currently selected cells", you can place the code in a regular module, altered as follows:

```
Public Sub DoStuff()
    Dim i As Range
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim A As String 'With "Long" it will Error, you're looking for "NEW"

    Set i = Intersect(Selection, Range("TestRange")) 
    If Not i Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cel In i
            A = UCase(Cel.Text)   'Would error if A was a Long
            If InStr(A, "NEW") Then       'Green text and bold
                With Cel.Font
                    .Color = -11489280
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Bold = True
                End With
            End If
       Next cel 'Was missing
    End If 'Was missing
End sub
```

Either way, your sample was not going to run, since

- your `For Each` loop was incomplete
- you were missing an `End If` statement
- you were passing a string into a Long variable

All three corrected in sample above.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm really inexperienced with VBA, and posts like this will help me learn it better.

Comment: Hoi Berend, you're welcome. We all start somewhere, keep it up. (Gewoon doorgaan, dan red je het wel)